# AJAX is failing to send data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am on this practice project of developing a login and sign up system of a Secret Diary. Everything else is working as it should and fine but I am stuck at this one part. Actually in the secret diary is a textarea and I am trying to make it so that whenever a change takes place in textarea, AJAX passes the data to a php file and php should update the database.

```
$("textarea").on("input propertychange", function() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "updatediary.php",
    data: {   
      content: $("textarea").val()
    }
  });
});
```

```php
<?php
  session_start();

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "cl44-secretdr", "********", "cl44-secretdr");

  if (mysqli_connect_error()) 
  {
    die ("Database Connection Error");
  }

  if (isset($_POST['content'])) 
  {
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `diary` = '".$_POST['content']."' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
  }
?>
```

Help me out please!

Comment: You're sending `content`, yet looking for `content1` in PHP. Closing as it's just a typo

Comment: I fixed that but still does not help. The database remains oblivious to any changes in textarea!

Comment: Are you sure a record with `id = $_SESSION['id']` exists in the DB? It could well be executing and not actually changing any data. Have you debugged exactly at what point the request is failing?

Comment: Yes I tried to debug it but still failed. When I remove the AJAX query and rewrite the PHP query in the same file which should update the data on a button click.....it happens and the db is updated. But when I change it to AJAX query which should update the db without a button click, it just doesnt do anything. And yes I checked the $_SESSION['id'] by echoing it, it works just fine

Comment: What happens if you `echo $_POST['content']`? There's not enough information here to help you, unfortunately, as what you have shown us should be working fine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He'll get `Array`. Use `var_dump($_POST);` instead.

Comment: if I echo $_POST['content'], it says undefined index!

Comment: Would you guys need access to the DB and the actual whole code? I dont mind giving it away since its a practice project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using? Before the 1.9 version the "method" attribute of the ajax request is called "type". Maybe if you change that attribute it will work.

Comment: jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js

Comment: If you do `var_dump($_POST)` you get an empty array?

Comment: Yes I get an empty array

Comment: Can you post the HTML? There's only one texarea? The ajax is executed when you want to? Maybe it's executed before any text is inserted in the textarea. Is there any link where we can try it? The code seems to be ok.

Comment: sure. You can have the current bugged version of the project here: http://www.henryspike.tk/6-php/secret-diary Yes there is one one text area!

Comment: Try to change the "input propertychange" for "keyup" event. When I write something in the textarea the `alert('success')` that appears in the source code of the website doesn't prompt.

Comment: Well I found something. If I remove the ajax part and just write alert("success") it works all the fine on every input change. The problem is with AJAX probably or the php not processing. Got any idea? Tell me if you need source code

Comment: Ok. If you watch the console in Chrome, when you write something in the textarea it shows an error that says `Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`. Be sure that the jQuery version you are loading has all the libraries. Try to load another version of jQuery to see if it works. Use the Console in Chrome to see the errors and the response of the ajax request.

Comment: I LOVE YOU , I LOVE YOU , I LOVE YOU!!!!!! I spent all my day , around 4 hours fixing this. The jquery I used was slim version, something that bootstrap template already had. I replaced that with Google CDN and it works. I was just about to give up programming for good but you are the man. Much respect!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("textarea").on("input propertychange", function() {

var obj={'val':$("textarea").val()};
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'updatediary.php',
        data:obj,
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}); 

    <?php
      session_start();

      $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "cl44-secretdr", "********", "cl44-secretdr");

      if (mysqli_connect_error()) 
      {
        die ("Database Connection Error");
      }

      if (isset($_POST['val'])) 
      {
        $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `diary` = '".$_POST['val']."' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Well I tried that as well, still does not update the database. I double checked the password and everything!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  

$("textarea").on("input propertychange", function() {
value = $("textarea").val();
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'updatediary.php',
        data:{content:value},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}); 

});
</script>
```

AND

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "cl44-secretdr", "********", "cl44-secretdr");

  if (mysqli_connect_error()) 
  {
    die ("Database Connection Error");
  }

  $id =$_SESSION['id'];
  $content = $_POST['content'];
  if (isset($content)) 
  {
    $query = "UPDATE users SET diary = '$content' WHERE id = {$id} ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
  }
?>
```